# Что здесь не так?

Tags: python, python-3.10

Я взял код для библиотеки silero,предварительно всё установив. Вот я запускаю код, и мне выдаёт ошибку

```
    Using cache found in C:\Users\79604/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\79604\Desktop\VoiceControl\speak.py", line 9, in <module>
    model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 404, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 433, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\79604/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 96, in silero_tts
    model = init_jit_model_tts(model_conf.jit)
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\dictconfig.py", line 357, in __getattr__
    self._format_and_raise(
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\base.py", line 231, in _format_and_raise
    format_and_raise(
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\_utils.py", line 873, in format_and_raise
    _raise(ex, cause)
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\_utils.py", line 771, in _raise
    raise ex.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])  # set env var OC_CAUSE=1 for full trace
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\dictconfig.py", line 353, in __getattr__
    return self._get_impl(
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\dictconfig.py", line 444, in _get_impl
    node = self._get_child(
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\basecontainer.py", line 73, in _get_child
    child = self._get_node(
  File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\omegaconf\dictconfig.py", line 482, in _get_node
    raise ConfigKeyError(f"Missing key {key!s}")
omegaconf.errors.ConfigAttributeError: Missing key jit
    full_key: tts_models.ru.v3_1_ru.latest.jit
    object_type=dict
```

Если надо то вот сам код:

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v3_1_ru'
device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'xenia'
put_accent=True
put_yo=True
example_text = 'В недрах тундры выдры в г+етрах т+ырят в вёдра ядра к+едров.'

audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yo=put_yo)
print(example_text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

Comment: Это возможно что-то с библиотекой torch, но я её переустановил

Comment: но не помогло к сожалению

Comment: В `Google Colab` нормально работает, но там питон старее. `!pip install -U silero` делали на всякий случай?

Comment: нет щас попробую

Comment: я использую VS Code

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению

Comment: В документации на `silero` есть альтернативный метод использования этой библиотеки вместо `torch.hub.load` через `import silero`, попробуйте его

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\79604\Desktop\VoiceControl\speak.py", line 10, in <module>
    model, example_text = silero(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Я пробовал `from silero import silero` и `silero.silero()`